# Cannot copy ssh key after generation

Tags: ssh

So I created a ssh key and can find the folder but on trying to copy,it won't work.Keeps telling me the system cannot find the path specified

My command prompt is on Windows,

Command
Clip <clip ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: You can open the file with notepad and copy it the "old-fashioned" way. But possibly what you are doing wrong is not using the full path (I don't think windows understands `~` in file paths).

Comment: `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` isn't a windows path, are you using "git-bash" or another linux-style terminal?

Comment: I am using git bash